# Generate Random Middle Initial in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-generation

How could I write a program in TSQL to go through each row of the table and generate a random letter for the middle initial column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple UPDATE statement instead of writing a program for it. An example would be (using the table/field names from your answer);

```
UPDATE Contact SET conMName = CHAR(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%26+65)
```

Comment: Damnit. There I go over thinking the problem.

Comment: I have actually never heard of the ABS function. That is pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Identity column held integers that incremented by one, the identity column was called conID, your table was called EDI.Contact and column that held middle names was called conMName, the folowing code would work;

```
DECLARE 
    @Counter INT = '1'
    , @GeneratedLetter CHAR(1)
    , @NumberOfRows INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EDI.Contact) -- Replace with your table name
    , @LetterNumber INT
WHILE (@Counter < @NumberOfRows +1)
BEGIN
SET @LetterNumber = (CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 26 as INT) + 1)
IF @LetterNumber = '1' 
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'A'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '2'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'B'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '3'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'C'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '4'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'D'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '5'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'E'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '6'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'F'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '7'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'G'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '8'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'H'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '9'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'I'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '10'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'J'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '11'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'K'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '12'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'L'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '13'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'M'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '14'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'N'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '15'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'O'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '16'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'P'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '17'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'Q'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '18'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'R'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '19'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'S'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '20'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'T'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '21'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'U'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '22'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'V'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '23'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'W'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '24'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'X'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '25'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'Y'
ELSE IF @LetterNumber = '26'
SET @GeneratedLetter = 'Z'
UPDATE EDI.Contact -- Replace with your table name
SET conMName = @GeneratedLetter -- Replace with column that holds middle names
WHERE conId = @Counter -- Replace with identity column name
SET @Counter = (@Counter + 1)
END
```